# Hyperledger Composer - DateTime storage in asset

Tags: hyperledger-composer

This question is based upon my attemp to adapt the sample 'perishable-network' (https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/tree/master/packages/perishable-network) for my work.

Suppose I have an hyperledger composer asset called ShippingContract. Now I'd like to record the contract creation time in this asset (say when a  createContract() function is called ). How can I achieve this? I was using a DateTime member which was being set in chaincode.

The few articles/posts (some on SO itself) that talk about this suggest that we should not store random/current time in DateTime object through chaincode, as during consensus, each endorsing/committing node will come up with different value and lead to failure of transaction!

The perishable-network sample uses a DateTime member variable, but sets this using the setupdemo transaction timestamp value within the setupDemo transaction code itself!

```
const tomorrow = setupDemo.timestamp;
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    contract.arrivalDateTime = tomorrow;
```

First question: How is it possible to refer to the transaction timestamp within the same transaction itself? Is this timestamp set when endorsers first endorse the transaction?

Second question: 
I was thinking that instead of DateTime member variable, it might be better to use a String variable and set that to new Date().toString() (Javascript function) and then pass it as a parameter to the transaction processor function (instead of calculating it at *run-time* within the function). This way, since I'm passing in a fixed value instead of having the chaincode calculate it dynamically, I hope to overcome any issues with consensus.

Is this a good approach? Any issues therein? Any better way to do this?

Comment: @Paul O'Mahony Any inputs from you would be highly appreciated.